# Minimal vertex cover

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a vertex $u$ in a graph $G$, let $N_G(u) = \{v \in V (G)|\{u, v\} \in E(G)\}$. For $U \subseteq V(G)$, define $G\setminus U$ to be the induced subgraph of $G$ on the vertex set $V (G) \setminus U$.

Let $G$ be a graph. A subset $C \subseteq V(G)$ is a vertex cover  of
$G$ if for each $e \in E(G)$, $e\cap C \neq \phi$.  If $C$ is minimal
with respect to inclusion, then $C$ is called minimal vertex
cover of $G$, denoted by $\textbf{m}(G)$, is the maximum cardinality of minimal vertex cover of $G$.

> What is the relation between $\textbf{m}(G)$ and $\textbf{m}(G \setminus N_G(x))$, for some $x \in V(G)$? 
>   In particular, suppose $\deg_G(x)=1$,
>   what is the relation between $\textbf{m}(G)$ and $\textbf{m}(G \setminus N_G(x))$?

Comment: Note that in the absence of "self-edges", the set $N_G(u)$ will not include $u$.  The implication is that vertex $u$ becomes an isolated vertex in $G\setminus N_G(u)$.  Your Question would be improved by adding such context as why this problem is important or interesting for you, and sharing the extent of your progress toward a solution.